# How to Decrease repository size?

Tags: templates, github, bitbucket, size

It happens that **repository size** increases more than allowed.

Usually it is **2 Gigabytes** cloud space.

What should be the solution for this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do share more details on your problem

Answer (score 0):

We can use git commands to decrease the Repository size in our local machine.Here are the commands :-

```
 git reflog expire --expire="1 hour" --all
 git reflog expire --expire-unreachable="1 hour" --all
 git prune --expire="1 hour" -v
 git gc --aggressive --prune="1 hour"
```